# Using a csv file in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csv

I have some data saved in .csv format. Basically I want to access this data within my Visual Studio project (using C#).

I've done some digging around and found things like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

But it just seems a little too complicated. Is there a **built-in method to read the csv file format within Visual Studio? If not I will start using the method shown there.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry perhaps I should be a little clearer. The csv file is huge (35,000 rows), I guess I should be asking how best to handle this data. Should I write it as a table, or read from the file each time I want to access the data?

If it sounds like I'm confusing terminology I'm sorry. I'm not all that familiar with C# and visual studio.

Comment: What do you mean by integrated?

Comment: **I meant built-in, sorry I'll change that.

Comment: Check out related links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550111/can-a-csv-file-be-used-as-a-data-source-in-visual-studio-2008?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library I've had good sucess with can be found as a download at CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

It provides a great deal of flexibility and has the ability to allow you to deal with malformed CSVs